# How to model a many:many relation in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I need to create a connection with a table that isn't in my control yet there's a **one-to-many** relationship so I'm having a bit of trouble with the hibernate mappings.

table1:

```
userId
firstname
lastname
```

table2:

```
user_id <= fk to table1.userId 
x_id
create_date
```

table3:

```
x_id
private1
private2
```

So my problem is that despite it being a **one-to-many** in reality I'll probably have to map it as a **many-to-many**. And a problem is that one of the column names in table 2 doesn't match the column name it references to in table 1. An additional problem I have is that in table 2 user_id and x_id form a combined primary key.

So far I've been using Hibernate mapping files and not annotations.
And I'd like to use an arraylist.

Comment: Does table2.x_id have a foreign key to table3.x_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you should map it as many to many relation using composite primary key.

Please see carefully ll the answers and questions on those posts it will help you.

[Mapping same class relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813941/mapping-same-class-relation)

and then

[Mapping same class relation - continuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845772/mapping-same-class-relation-continuation)

I think it have all the answers inside.