# Getting added with composite id in show form

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

My User.hbm file is like this ,

```
<composite-id>
    <key-property name="username" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="USERNAME"></column>
    </key-property>
    <key-property name="location" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="LOCATION"></column>
    </key-property>
</composite-id>
```

User class is like this,

```
private String username;
private String location;
```

getter and setter
I have overridden hashcode and equals method.

In my mvc form controller i am trying to display user related data

My jsp page

```
<div>
    <appfuse:label key="user.name" styleClass="desc"/>
    <form:input path="username" id="tag" cssClass="text medium" cssErrorClass="text  medium error"/>
</div>
```

My form controller.class

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String onSubmit(User user, BindingResult errors,
                           HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        LOG.debug("entering 'onSubmit' method ...");


        /////user.getUsername
    }
```

After i submit by form data , is getting added to the username

If i try to print user.getUsername it print name with , eg :,hello.

Can any one please explain why this happens how to solve it.?
Is it related to composite id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create inner static class which should be mapped as Composite Id.

[Mapping same class relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813941/mapping-same-class-relation)

[Mapping same class relation - continuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845772/mapping-same-class-relation-continuation)

Please look at this questions and answers it may help.

Comment: thanks i solved the issue.In hidden path i was using     <form:hidden path="userName"/>
<div>
    <appfuse:label key="user.name" styleClass="desc"/>
    <form:input path="username" id="tag" cssClass="text medium" cssErrorClass="text  medium error"/>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

thanks i solved the issue.In hidden path i was using
 `<form:hidden path="userName"/>`

```
<div>
    <appfuse:label key="user.name" styleClass="desc"/>
    <form:input path="username" id="tag" cssClass="text medium" cssErrorClass="text  medium error"/>
</div>
```

i removed hidden it solved issue