# hibernate - mapping PK to 2 colums

Tags: database, hibernate

i search the web for answer, but all the answers refer to composite id PK.
i want two map two columns of type long to PK.
one should be regular generated id, and the other should be regular long field.

i have the following mapping:

```
  <class name="com.company.MyTable" table="My_Table">
        <id name="id" column="id">            
            <generator class="assigned"/>
        </id>
        <property name="jobId" column="job_id" type="long" index="oes_job_id_idx" />
        <property name="serverId" column="server_id" type="long"/>
     </class>
```

i want to add to the PK the job_id column.
how do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Primary keys, by definition should be the unique key with the fewest columns possible:

- your can't have multiple primary keys
- you shouldn't use an additional column for the primary key, if the first column is already unique

It doesn't really give you a benefit to create a separate index either - so stick to the generated field as primary key. So, hibernate doesn't support that because it is a wrong thing to do.

Comment: currently i have a bug, on production application, and that is the only solution...
i have two tables, one backup the another. when backup the table, we copy also the id (assigned generator). after deleting the original table, it can contains the same id as an old row. when backup again, i will fail on duplicate key. therefore, i need another specific column as PK

Comment: @yonatan then the id is _not_ auto-generated. Then you can simply use composite IDs

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this questions there is a full solution for composite Primary keys:

[Mapping same class relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813941/mapping-same-class-relation)

And then

[Mapping same class relation - continuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845772/mapping-same-class-relation-continuation)

Hope it helps.

Comment: both links related to composite PK: the PK there is pointing on different entity / list...