# Many to many hibernate mapping with extra columns?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Hi i have many to many mapping with extra columns in the join table.
table structure look like this.

```
table vendor{vendor_id, vendor_name, vendor_password, etc...}
table student{student_id, student_name, student_password, etc..}
table test{test_id, test_subject, test_price,test_level, etc..}
```

Relations as follows

```
vendor to test --> many-to-many
student to test --> many-to-many
```

link

```
table vendor_student_test{vendor_id, student_id, test_id, purchasedDate, assignedDate, writtenDate, result}
```

i created POJO classes as follows

1. Vendor.java

> ```
> public class Vendor {
> Long vendorId;
> Set<VendorStudentTest> tests;
> //set and get
> }
> ```

1. Student.java

> ```
> public class Student{
> Long studentId;
> Set<VendorStudentTest> tests;
> //set and get
> }
> ```

1. Test.java

> ```
> public class Test{
> Long test_id;
> double test_price;
> //set and get and remaining fields
> }
> ```

1. VendorStudentTest.java

> ```
> public class VendorStudentTest{
> public VendorStudentTestPK vendorStudentTestPK;
> Date purchasedDate;
> Date assignDate;
> Date writtenDate;
> double result;
> //set and get accordingly
> }
> ```

1. VendorStudentTestPK.java

> ```
> public class VendorStudentTestPK{
> Long vendor_id;
> Long student_id;
> Long test_id;
> }
> ```

Hibernate mapping files as follows

vendor.hbm.xml

```
<set name="tests" table="vendor_student_test"
                inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="vendor_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="VendorStudentTest" />
        </set>
```

vendor_student_test.hbm.xml

```
    <composite-id name="vendorStudentTestPK"
        class="com.onlineexam.model.VendorStudentTestPK">

        <key-property name="vendor" column="vendor_id"
            type="java.lang.Long" />
        <key-property name="student" column="student_id"
            type="java.lang.Long" />
        <key-property name="test" column="test_id" type="java.lang.Long" />

    </composite-id>
```

student.hbm.xml

```
<set name="tests" table="vendor_student_test"
                inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="student_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="VendorStudentTest" />
        </set>
```

test.hbm.xml

```
//this is mapped to other table
```

I am new to hibernate, Is this correct mapping?

Answer (score 1):

solution with Annotation Case can be found here

[How Do I Create Many to Many Hibernate Mapping for Additional Property from the Join Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294338/many-to-many-hibernate-mapping-for-additional-property-in-the-join-table/10301484#10301484)

Solution using xml file can be found here:
[Mapping same class relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813941/mapping-same-class-relation)

and here:

[Mapping same class relation - continuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845772/mapping-same-class-relation-continuation)

Comment: So, refer to last two links. It explains everything you need to know.

Comment: hi i have updated the mappings, can u tell me is that correct.