# Three-way hibernate ORM mapping - how to?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a three SQL tables:

```
create table users (
  id serial primary key,
  name text not null unique
);

create table posts (
  id serial primary key,
  data text not null,
  authorId integer not null references users (id)
);

create table ratings (
  id serial primary key,
  name text not null unique
);
```

One post can have only one author, so `users` <-> `posts` relation is already established in normal form (correct me if i am wrong).

Ratings are pre-defined constants like "bad", "good" or "awesome", with (in real case) additional data as rating value, description or other fields i omitted here for brevity.

Next i want to relate ratings to users and posts. Each post may be rated once by each user, and may be rated by multiple users. I came up with the following relation:

```
create table posts_ratings_users_map (
  postId integer not null references posts (id),
  ratingId integer not null references ratings (id),
  userId integer not null references users (id),
  primary key (postId, ratingId, userId)
);
```

But here is the problem: i can't see a way to integrate it within Hibernate ORM mapping, to get for each of posts list (or set, or any other collection) of pairs of (User,Rating).

Here is how i am trying to map them now:

User.java:

```
@Entity(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "authorId")
    private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<>();

    // ...
    // getters and setters
    // ...
}
```

Rating.java:

```
@Entity(name = "ratings")
public class Rating {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "ratings")
    private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<>();

    // ...
    // getters and setters
    // ...
}
```

Post.java:

```
@Entity(name = "posts")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String data;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "authorId")
    private User author;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "posts_ratings_users_map",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ratingId") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "postId") }
    )
    private Set<Rating> ratings = new HashSet<>(); // here is the problem. i can relate ratings to this post, but how
                                                   // do i relate them with users which assigned their ratings to this
                                                   // post ?


    // ...
    // getters and setters
    // ...
}
```

What needs to be changed in order to relate list of pairs of rating&user to each post?

**UPD1**

Obvious error: PK for posts_ratings_users_map should be `(postId, userId)` (excluding `ratingId`), otherwise same user was able to put different ratings on the same post.

Comment: I say you need another table. `user_post_rating` with user_id, post_id and rating_id columns and all there as a combination primary key. This table will store data on which user gave which rating to which post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe change your model a little.

Users have posts which you said is already defined.

Why not create a new Entity 'UserRating'.

```
@Entity(name = "user_ratings")
public class UserRating {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(nullable = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ratingId")
    private Rating rating;

    @ManyToOne(nullable = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "authorId")
    private User ratedBy;
 }
```

Now on your `Post` instead of the `ManyToMany` have a `OneToMany` relationship. It would be more ideal to use the id of the rating and the user as the key for the `UserRating` class but this doesnt model easily in JPA/Hibernate which makes it quite complex. If your interested have a look at these questions

[Mapping ManyToMany with composite Primary key and Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405746/mapping-manytomany-with-composite-primary-key-and-annotation)

[Many to many hibernate mapping with extra columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416263/many-to-many-hibernate-mapping-with-extra-columns)

Comment: This is exactly how I would do it, too. You get something very naturally understandable by introducing a UserRating - even managers would understand that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Include the user in the rating class

```
@Entity(name = "ratings")
public class Rating {
@Id
@Column(nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "ratings")
private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<>();

@Onetoone
private User ratedBy;

// ...
// getters and setters
// ...
}
```

Comment: rating table is just a predefined set of ratings like GOOD, BAD, EXCELLENT. you will need a mapping table with rating_id, post_id and user_id to store real info.

Comment: @shazinltc
Sorry, but unfortunately this won't work out that simple. Just because this annotation won't provide a hint in which table perform one-to-one (also, it is case-sensitive, `@OneToOne`) relation, nor by which column, nor how at all.

Comment: I find this not very intuitive.