# Questions in one-to-many hibernate mapping

Tags: hibernate, arraylist, indexing, one-to-many, bag

I've checked many topics opened on stackoverflow but I didn't really get answers to my questions. Ok, let's consider this example using **ArrayList** :

```
public class Stock implements java.io.Serializable {     
    private Integer stockId;
    private String stockCode;
    private String stockName;
    private ArrayList<StockDailyRecord> stockDailyRecords = new ArrayList<StockDailyRecord>(); 
    //getter, setter and constructor
}
public class StockDailyRecord implements java.io.Serializable { 
    private Integer recordId;
    private Stock stock;
    private Float priceOpen;
    private Float priceClose;
    private Float priceChange;
    private Long volume;
    private Date date;

    //getter, setter and constructor
}
```

So we can say association from Stock to StockDailyRecord it **one-to-many**. And it's what I'm trying to map in **Stock.hbm.xml**. I read that while mapping by the **list** tag, we need an **index**.

So my 1st question is : is it possible to keep the **index list** empty??

```
<list name="stockDailyRecords" table="stock_daily_record" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
    <key>
        <column name="STOCK_ID" not-null="true" />
    </key>
    <list-index></list-index>
    <one-to-many class="com.mkyong.stock.StockDailyRecord" />
</list>
```

My second question : Let's suppose now that I add in my table **STOCKDAILYRECORD** ( in database ) a column called **indexCol**. So in Conception we would have : every Stock has a list of StockDailyRecord, ordered from 0 to x.. It means that **indexCol is unique relatively to its Stock**, but **not unique in STOCKDAILYRECORD**. Is it correct what I think?

My third question is about a solution I found on stackoverflow here : [Hibernate one to many mapping works with a list but not a set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580686/hibernate-one-to-many-mapping-works-with-a-list-but-not-a-set), in the highest voted answer, it says that we can **Declare the object as Collection and instantiate it as ArrayList** and use **bag** in the xml mapping file if we want to avoid **list**. So is it possible to **declare it ArrayList instead of Collection?** Thank you a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

What's is the problem using List? You can manage it as arraylist. For example:

```
<bag name="stockDailyRecords" table="stock_daily_record" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
<key column="STOCK_ID"/>
<many-to-many column="recordId" fetch="select" lazy="false" class="com.mkyong.stock.StockDailyRecord"/>
</bag>
```

Remember that ArrayList implements List interface, by the way, these two objects have the same methods.

Comment: So you mean that we can use in our Model "ArrayList" or "List", and use in mapping "bag", without any problem?

Comment: Yes, but can you explain why do you need to instantiate the List as ArrayList?

Comment: because List is an abstract class, we can't instantiate it, we can only declare  an object as a list, kind of expecting a polymorphism.. but polymorphism is not needed in my case so i can declare it and instantiate it as ArrayList

Comment: you can do that with `List<StockDailyRecord> stockDailyRecords = new ArrayList<>();`